# How to start with fbx-conv? "Command not found" issue

Tags: linux, macos, libgdx, fbx

does anyone know how to use fbx-conv with mac? I downloaded the zip file here : http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/fbx-conv/

The command line with `fbx-conv-mac thePathOfMyFile` did not work, it always says "**command not found**". Then the ReadMe file :

> On Linux and Mac, we have to link to the dynamic libraries of the FBX SDK (libfbxsdk.so and libfbxsdk.dylib). We recommend copying libfbxsdk.so
>   to /usr/lib on Linux. Otherwise you can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH and set it to the directory you put the .so file.

I only have the `.dylib` file so I tried to copy it in `/usr/lib` with : `sudo cp /Users/MyName/fbx-conv/libfbxsdk.dylib /usr/lib` , it worked, the file was copied to this folder, but the command line `fbx-conv-mac thePathOfMyFile` still does not work: **command not found**.

Still in the ReadMe, it says :

> Building
>   You'll need premake and an installation of the FBX SDK 2014. Once installed/downloaded, set the
>   FBX_SDK_ROOT to the directory where you installed the FBX SDK. Then run one of the 
>   generate_XXX scripts. These will generate a Visual Studio/XCode project, or a Makefile.

On Google, with FBX SDK 2014, I found this link to download `fbx-conv-master` : https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv which looks like the folder with the good files, but I don't know how to use them, there are no `fbx-conv` for example.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but i think the "...have to link to the dynamic libraries of the FBX SDK..." is only neccessary if you build it yourself. You can also download the binary you can directly execute. The "command not found" issue is probably, because you need to navigate to the folder, where the FBX-Conv is, to execute it. On windows you can navigate using the command "cd" (change directory). Navigate to the folder, where the binary is and execute again.

Comment: @Springrbua about `cd`, I am already doing it to the fbx-conv folder, then when I am inside this folder : `fbx-conv-mac thePathToTheFile` but it says "command not found" (the exec file is named `fbx-conv-mac`), even the name alone does not let me see the options, as I read in a post, it also says "command not found", so it is maybe a problem with the installation?

Comment: I don't have much experience with linux and no experience with mac. So i can't help you out here.  
It seems, like you really need to link those files, even if you use the precompiled binaries...

Comment: @Springrbua thanks I appreciate the help. Do you think you could help me with a PC? I found a pc, I downloaded the `VC 2010 Redistributable Package` as said in the ReadMe file, I downloaded Blender for pc, exported a fbx file, and i have got this error : `FBX SDK encountered an error : Unknown` after : `INFO: FBX to G3Dx converter, version 0.01.0000 x32 pre-release`, then `STATUS : Loading source file`, and then the error. Cannot find much on google, have you had this experience before? Anything I could try?

Comment: @KumarSaurabh @Springrbua OK I got an answer from the libgdx forum, on Mac the solution was to write `./fbx-conv-mac filePath` instead of `fbx-conv-mac filePath`. It works for me.

Comment: Ah okay^^ Yea right should be the same on linux, as the "." stands for the current foler and "/" is the separator. So with "./fbx-conv" you say "current-folder/fbx-conv". Good that you found the solution! Post it as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I got an answer from the libgdx forum, on Mac the solution was to write `./fbx-conv-mac filePath` instead of `fbx-conv-mac filePath`. It works for me.